# Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n+4}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n+4}$ diverges?

I tried integrating $\frac{\ln (x)}{x+4}$ using integration by parts but that does not seem to work.

Comment: What do you know about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+4}$?

Comment: If you're dead-set on using the Integral Test, by either Comparison Test it suffices to consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For $x>e$,
$$\frac{\ln x}{x+4}>\frac1{x+4}$$ and you can use the integral test on the $RHS$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n+4}\geq   \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n+4}\geq \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+4}=\infty
\end{align*}
where the second inequality is because $\ln(n)\geq 1$ if $n\geq 3$ and the first inequality is because I eliminated some terms and $\ln(n)\geq 0$ when $n=1,2$.

Thus, the series is divergent.

If you don't like comparing infinite sum,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\ln(n)}{n+4}\geq   \sum_{n=3}^{N} \frac{\ln(n)}{n+4}\geq \sum_{n=3}^{N}\frac{1}{n+4}
\end{align*}

And send $N$ to infinity and see the right most hand side goes infinity.